# Tkinter how to stop grid from closing empty cells

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I have a GUI that will size itself to the appropriate proportions dependent on the size of the display. It then needs to divide itself **evenly** into 160,000 cells by having its columnspan=400 and rowspan=400.

I have specific widgets that need to be in specific cells, and some of the cells need to be empty, but the GUI just collapses all of the empty cells.

This code is intended to make the label (background) be near the bottom of the page, but it appears a the top left because its crushing all of the empty rows.

Is my only answer to this to use empty frames to take up space?

```
import tkinter as Tk

root= Tk.Tk()


def window(main):
    main.title('Bible Helper')
    width= int(main.winfo_screenwidth()*0.5)
    height= int(main.winfo_screenheight()*0.75)
    x= (main.winfo_screenwidth()//2)- (width // 2)
    y= (main.winfo_screenheight()//2)- (height//2)-20
    main.geometry('%sx%s+%s+%s' % (width, height, x, y))
    root.update_idletasks()


window(root)


root_frame = Tk.Frame(root, width=root.winfo_width(), height=root.winfo_height(), bg="black")
root_frame.grid_propagate(0) #Stops child widgets of root_frame from resizing it
root_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=400, columnspan=400)


background= Tk.Label(root_frame, text="BH", font=("Arial", 100, "bold"), background ="black", anchor="se", padx=35, pady=15, foreground= 'white')
background.grid(row=306, rowspan=94, sticky="NWSE")


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was just a simple mistake on my end of making the parent widget the frame instead of root.